# Trouble reading escape characters from an input value

Tags: php, post, escaping

So right now my input form looks something like this

```
<form method = "post" action = "Display_Department_Info.php">
            Select Department :
            <select name = "dept">
            <option value="" selected >-- Select One--</option>
            <?php
            $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'DM Phase 2');
            if(!$conn) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
            }
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, 'select name from department');
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $val = $row['name'];
                echo "<option value ='".$val."'>".$val."</option>";
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
            </select>   
            <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />

        </form>
```

but when I use the following command to read `$_POST[dept]` for a particular input 
"Children's IKEA", it only displays "Children"

This is my reading code.

```
$departmentinput = mysql_real_escape_string("$_POST[dept]");
```

Please help! thank you :3

Answer (score 1):

The `'` is breaking it because you are using `'` to quote the value:

```
$val = htmlspecialchars($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES);

//or

$val = htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES);
```